# When typing on iPhone, screen zooms in?

Tags: html, css, iphone, safari, mobile-safari

## Hello

I am building a chat room site, however it runs into a problem on iPhone (or possibly safari I have not checked yet).

When you start typing in the input which is `position: fixed` to the bottom, the screen zooms in, and you have to manually zoom out to see the send button. I know this was not very explanatory, so I will put my code here:

#### Sloppy code that works sometimes (except now)

```
input {
  font-size: 150%;
  width: 83vw;
  height: inherit;
}

form {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: -2px;
  height: 6vh;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

form button {
  width: calc(17vw + 2px);
  font-size: 150%;
  position: fixed;
  right: -2px;
  height: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not anything to do with your code. I am a long time iphone user and could say that iphone does this automatically. When the keybord is initiated it automatically zoom to a point where you can see what you are typing effectievly.

Comment: So is there anything I can do?

Comment: for iphone automatically zooming: I am afraid not.

Comment: Just a note: theoretically, you could listen to the blur event on the input to reset the zoom for the user so if the user clicks outside the input it automatically re adjust the window. Though i have not tried this; or could adjust the size of the input to make the zooming less obvious